# Saving JS Code into RCloud Asset Book and Calling it in Shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny, rcloud

How would you put in java script code in an asset book and call it in shiny code? having some trouble getting it to work. I need to find a way to get that in a asset book in RCloud, and be able to call it within Rcloud, without having to reference the code online

```
#Link to JS Code I am trying to save inside Rcloud
```

tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js

```
# Call asset to provide JS Code
```

tinymce.fn.source  <- rcloud.get.asset("tinymce.js", notebook=assetsNotebook)
source(textConnection(tinymce.fn.source))

```
Side Text Panel Code

                      fluidRow(
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src ="tinymce.fn.source"))),
                        column(12, offset = 0,
                               hr(),
                               h4('Side Panel Text'),
                               uiOutput("editor1"))),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted [this example from The Dub World](https://thedubworld.wordpress.com/2016/03/13/adding-a-html-editor-to-shiny/):

```
library(rcloud.shiny)
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(tags$head(tags$script(src='/notebook.R/6a4819a38814bdad910e837f0c4de702/tinymce.min.js')),

   # Application title
   fluidRow(
      titlePanel('tinyMCE Modal Example'),
      br(),
      actionButton('modal', 'Modal Example', icon=icon('paper-plane-o'), class='btn-success', style='margin-left:15px;',`data-toggle`='modal', `data-target`='#modalExample'),
      br(),br(),
      tags$pre(htmlOutput('modalText')),
      ### Modal ###
      tags$div(class='modal fade', id='modalExample', tabindex='-1', role='dialog',`aria-labelledby`='modalExample', `aria-hidden`='true',
         tags$div(class='modal-dialog', role='document',
             tags$div(class='modal-content',
                 tags$div(class='modal-header', tags$button(type='button', class='close', `data-dismiss`='modal', `aria-label`='Close', tags$span(`aria-hidden`='true', 'x')),tags$h4(class='modal-title', 'HTML Editor in a modal')),
                 tags$div(class='modal-body', tags$form(method='post', tags$textarea(id='modalEditor')),tags$script("tinymce.init({selector:'#modalEditor', theme: 'modern', height: 200});")),
                 tags$div(class='modal-footer',tags$button(type='button', class='btn btn-primary', `data-dismiss`='modal', onclick="Shiny.onInputChange('modalTextArea',tinyMCE.get('modalEditor').getContent());",'Close')))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$modalText <- renderUI({
        req(input$modalTextArea)
        HTML(enc2utf8(input$modalTextArea))
  })
}

rcloud.shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I saved the JS to my Desktop, then loaded using the File Upload GUI **ticking the Upload to notebook box** to create an RCloud Asset:

[image: Create Javascript RCloud Asset]

Click on the **link icon** in the RCloud Asset section and you will see the JS code loaded as a notebook.R static asset:

[image: notebook.R interface to RCloud Asset]

[The notebook.R interface (web service)](http://rcloud.social/documentation/doc/1.8/guidoc/doc.html#notebook.r) allows you to call a [static asset using the relative path of your notebook](https://rcloud.social/edit.html?notebook=6a4819a38814bdad910e837f0c4de702)...so you can create functions in other notebooks and call them using that path, for example.

Comment: So i see you are still calling the javascript from the internet. //cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js. I am trying to have that code in an asset book inside RCloud to avoid calling the code online.

Comment: use the notebook.R interface...I will adapt the code.